# Stuck on recursion algorithm in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I got stuck with the following task:
"Write a recursive function that takes a one-dimensional array of 100 randomly set integers and finds the position at which a sequence of 10 numbers begins with the minimum sum".

I've written 2 functions:

```
int recursiveArrSum(int mass[], int dim = 10, int sum = 0) {
    if (dim == 0) return sum;
    sum += mass[dim-1];
    return recursiveArrSum(mass, --dim, sum);
}

int recArrMinSum(int mass[], int dim=100, int tempSum=100, int idx=0, int addPar=0){
    if (dim == 0) return idx;
    mass[dim]=mass[addPar];
    
    if (tempSum >= recursiveArrSum(mass)){
        tempSum = recursiveArrSum(mass);
        idx = dim-1;
        //mass[dim]=mass[addPar];
    }return recArrMinSum(mass, --dim, tempSum, idx, ++addPar);
```

1st one (recursiveArrSum) - works fine, but the second one drives me crazy...

I can't understand how I need to iterate an array during evoking the function on last return statement. I made it using for loop, and it works correctly:

```
for (int i=0; i<91; i++){
        int tempS=0;
        for (int j=i; j<=i+9; j++){
            tempS += arr[j];
            cout << tempS<< endl;
        }
        if (tempS<tempSum) {
            tempSum=tempS;
            k=i+1;
       }
}
```

but recursion doesn't...

Could anyone suggest me the way for solving this issue?
Open for any questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make sure I understand the question: among all possible 10 elements sequences in your 100 elements array, you want the one whose sum is minimal?

Comment: @m88, Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The line `mass[dim]=mass[addPar];` is mysterious - why are you modifiying the input array? (The word "addPar" provides no clue at all.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, using this I'm trying to iterate an array in forward direction ( from 0th to 99th position). Otherwise it will iterate backwards...

Comment: when the array has `dim` elements then `mass[dim]` is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I don't see how ruining the caller's array helps with that.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, I've tried  mass[dim-1], and it has the same behaviour. I can't figure out, how I can evoke the recursive function with the next element of "big" array... How I can move from mass[0] to mass[1]... etc.

Comment: The thing is that its not clear what `mass[dim]=mass[addPar];` is supposed to do. " using this I'm trying to iterate an array in forward direction ( from 0th to 99th position). Otherwise it will iterate backwards..." is still a bit "mysterious". What does assigning to `mass[dim]` have to do with the direction you iterate?

Comment: @molbdnilo, I've tried also in backward direction, but still it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

A function that keeps in its arguments the current position, the current sum, the minimum sum and the starting position of this minimum sum. The function also transports as arguments the array (obviously), its size and the dimension of the sum (10 in your case).

```
void compute(int mass[], int massSize = 100, int dim = 10, int currentPosition = 0, int currentSum = 0, int minSum = 99999, int minPosition = -1)
{
    // Before suming the first dim elements, we keep going adding the element at the current position and we increase the current position.
    if (currentPosition < dim) 
    {
        compute(mass, massSize, dim, currentPosition + 1, currentSum + mass[currentPosition], minSum, minPosition);
        return;
    }
    
    // When reaching the end of the array, we print our best solution.
    if (currentPosition > massSize)
    {
        std::cout << "Min sum of " << dim << " elements is " << minSum << ", starting at position " << minPosition << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    
    // In all the other cases, we check if the current sum is better than the minimum sum. If yes, we update the minimum sum and its starting position. Then call again the function!
    if (currentSum < minSum)
    {
        minSum = currentSum;
        minPosition = currentPosition - dim;
    }
    
    compute(mass, massSize, dim, currentPosition + 1, currentSum + mass[currentPosition ] - mass[currentPosition -dim], minSum, minPosition);
}
```

Calling the function is easy: `compute(mass, SIZE, 10);` where `mass` is your array, `SIZE` is its size and `10` is your dimension.

With a dimension equals to 5 in this array:

```
8; 8; 4; 10; 9; 9; 6; 3; 3; 5; 3; 8; 3; 7; 9; 10; 10; 5; 6; 4; 1; 4; 1; 5; 2; 8; 6; 1; 7; 9; 
Min sum of 5 elements is 13, starting at position 20
```

When writing a recursive function, the first things to do is to think about the exit case, the init cases (if there are any) and the "classic" case when you're in the middle of your search.

Feel free to ask any question, I added some comments to make it clear enough.

Comment: Sorry I posted with some typo. I changed the variable names to be clearer, that should be okay now.

Comment: don't worry, I've found typos by myself) Thanks a lot, your code solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how your code is supposed to work. To iterate the array and find the smallest sum you do something like this (pseudo code):

```
 int currentSum = sum of elements 0 till 9
 int smallestSum = currentSum
 int smallestIndex = 0
 for (i = 10; i < 100; ++i) {
       currentSum = currentSum - mass[ i -10] + mass[i]
       if (currentSum < smallestSum) {
            smallestSum = currentSum
            smallestIndex = i
       }
 }
```

As initial guess it takes the sum of the first 10 elements, ie elements 0 till 9. After that it iterates the array. Sum of elements 1 till 10 is the same as sum of elements 0 till 9 minus first element plus element 10. More general: To get the sum in the next iteration, element at `i-10` is subtracted and element at `i` is added.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but this is not a recursive algorithm as the OP asked.

Comment: @BNilsou I know. Though, it can be turned into something recursive

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, seems, that your version of pseudo is what I've mentioned. Also I've put the code with for-loops which is working in a main post)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're allowed to include from the STL, but there's this solution:

```
// Or std::pair<int, int*>
struct resultPair {
    int first;
    int* second;
};

// Or std::accumulate
int sumOf(int* arr, size_t s) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<s; ++i)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}

resultPair minSeqOfN(int* arr, size_t s, size_t N) {
    if (s < N) throw; // Or however you want to check pre-conditions

    int sum = sumOf(arr, N);
    
    if (s == N) return { sum, arr }; // Base case
    auto nextRes = minSeqOfN(arr+1, s-1, N);
    if (nextRes.first < sum) return nextRes;
    else return resultPair{sum, arr};
}
```

The function keeps calling itself minus the first element, until the sequence size is equal to the input array size (then there's just 1 possible answer).

Comment: sorry, I'm studying c++ couple of month, and I can't use such methods so far

Comment: we can't use pointers and structures so far... As long as we'll cover them I'll check your code, but I believe it's working. Thank you very much for responsiveness!